# Getting selected values without redirecting to another page using Jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to get the selected value from dropdown using Jquery. But when I click on the option its redirecting to another page and because of that I could not able to see output on the console. can anyone help me out with the code?

This is what I tried

```
if(typeof jQuery == "undefined"){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uniqName_7_0DefaultSelect").change(function() {
            var selectedText = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            console.log(selectedText);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `preventDefault()` to prevent default action :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uniqName_7_0DefaultSelect").change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var selectedText = $('option:selected', this).text();
        console.log(selectedText);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#uniqName_7_0DefaultSelect").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedText = $('option:selected', this).text();
    console.log(selectedText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="uniqName_7_0DefaultSelect"> 
  <option value="valeur1">Option 1</option> 
  <option value="valeur2">Option 2</option> 
  <option value="valeur3">Option 3</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the code. Still I am getting Undefined in the console.

Comment: Check my updated answer please using `$('option:selected', this).text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault and return false in the function may help

```
if(typeof jQuery == "undefined"){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uniqName_7_0DefaultSelect").change(function(e) {
            var selectedText = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            console.log(selectedText);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;` fo the same thing, so no need for duplicate answers, the `e.preventDefault();` suggestion already posted ~5 min before your answer.

Comment: Hi Patel, Thanks for the code. still I am getting undefined in the console